# Parent method is not recognized by child - JavaScript Prototype Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

--- apparently I did a mistake and the following code DOES work... ---

I am new to JavaScript and prototype inheritance. I come from a class-based inheritance language background.

I'm trying to create a parent object that does some stuff in it's prototype's methods. It has a certain method (doSomething) that inside it calls another method (doNestedSomething).

```
function Parent (num)
{
    this.num = num;
}

Parent.prototype.doSomething = function()
{
    this.doNestedSomething();
};

Parent.prototype.doNestedSomething = function()
{
    this.num++;
    console.log(this.num);
};
```

Then I want to create a child that inherits from the super, and overrides the certain method.

```
function Child (num, st)
{
    this.st = st;

    Parent.call(this, num);
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

Child.prototype.doSomething = function()
{
    this.st += " " + this.st;
    console.log(this.st);

    Parent.prototype.doSomething.call(this);
};
```

The problem is, that once it calls the super's doSomething method, inside it the doNestedSomething method somehow does not exist.

```
var child = new Child(0, "kawaii");
child.doSomething(); //Uncaught TypeError: this.doNestedSomething is not a function
```

I think I'm doing something wrong. I looked around [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) about inheritance and prototype and tried to implement it as depicted there.
But I can not find any information on how a child can call a super method, when the super method calls some other super method...

I looked at John Resig's [way](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) to implement inheritance, but still do not see there an example for a child indirectly calling a parent method that does not exist...

Comment: I don't get any error running your code.

Comment: Same here - works just fine - see [this](http://codepen.io/garin/pen/JdRNzm) pen

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry apparently it does work, I was runing it without the `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` ... should I delete the question???

Comment: No problem. Personally I think it's a nice example of JavaScript inheritance. Could be useful to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested your exemple and it works well,

For :

```
var child = new Child(0, "kawaii");
child.doSomething();
child.doSomething();
child.doSomething();
```

It output without exception :

```
kawaii kawaii
1
kawaii kawaii kawaii kawaii
2
kawaii kawaii kawaii kawaii kawaii kawaii kawaii kawaii
3
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/uwb7omx3/

Tested on chrome 42

Comment: You are right, I was running it without the `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);` ...